# Extract data from span tag within a div tag

Tags: python, html

I have the html code below and I'm trying to extract the 3:40 as text to use in my python script.  How would I go about grabbing that info?

[example element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsQfa.png)

Comment: instead of putting up the image, write the code.

Comment: What are you using? XPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library. Here is how I would grap this info knowning that you already have the HTML file :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open(html_path) as html_file:
    html_page = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'html.parser')
    div = html_page.find('div', class_='playbackTimeline__duration')
    span = div.find('span', {'aria-hidden': 'true'})
    text = span.get_text()
```

I'm not sure if it works, but it gives you an idea on how to do this kind of stuff. Check for "web scraping" if you want more information about that. :)